# Popup window expand when clicking link to new popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a popup (432x296px) and when I click a link for a new popup I need the width to expand to 810px. Right now the 2nd popup window stays the same width even though I specified the width just like i did with the 1st one. It seems there's a problem when going from popup to popup.

How can I expand the width when navigating from popup to popup? BTW the 2nd popup will contain an iframe so I'll need to specify the width.

Here's how I'm calling the popups.

```
function popup(){
 popupWindow = window.open("example-popup.html", "littleWindow", "location=no,width=810,height=468");
}

<a href="javascript:popup()"></a>
```

Comment: are you opening second popup in first one?

Comment: Yes. I would like the page to open a popup, and then from that popup go to another popup.

Comment: can you create a fiddle of what have you done...bcoz it will be easier for us to find the solution